# Generate list of all palindromic numbers of 3 digits in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools, palindrome

I want to generate list of all palindromic numbers of 3 digits in python. I can code this in a crude way but is there some intuitive way using list comprehension or `itertools` etc?

And also, How to do it if it is given the number is `k` digits instead of just 3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> L = [int("%d%d%d" % (x,y,x)) for x in range(1,10) for y in range(10)]
>>> L
[101, 111, 121, 131, 141, 151, 161, 171, 181, 191, 202, 212, 222, 232, 242, 252,
 262, 272, 282, 292, 303, 313, 323, 333, 343, 353, 363, 373, 383, 393, 404, 414,
 424, 434, 444, 454, 464, 474, 484, 494, 505, 515, 525, 535, 545, 555, 565, 575,
 585, 595, 606, 616, 626, 636, 646, 656, 666, 676, 686, 696, 707, 717, 727, 737,
 747, 757, 767, 777, 787, 797, 808, 818, 828, 838, 848, 858, 868, 878, 888, 898,
 909, 919, 929, 939, 949, 959, 969, 979, 989, 999]
```

**UPDATE:** To be more memory and speed efficient, you can replace string formatting and int conversion by `x+y*10+x*100`. Thanks @larsmans.

**UPDATE 2:** And that's for `k` digits!

```
[int(''.join(map(str, (([x]+list(ys)+[z]+list(ys)[::-1]+[x]) if k%2
                  else ([x]+list(ys)+list(ys)[::-1]+[x])))))
            for x in range(1,10)
            for ys in itertools.permutations(range(10), k/2-1)
            for z in (range(10) if k%2 else (None,))]
```

And that's optimized to NOT use strings!

```
[sum([n*(10**i) for i,n in enumerate(([x]+list(ys)+[z]+list(ys)[::-1]+[x]) if k%2
                                else ([x]+list(ys)+list(ys)[::-1]+[x]))])
            for x in range(1,10)
            for ys in itertools.permutations(range(10), k/2-1)
            for z in (range(10) if k%2 else (None,))]
```

I used permutations, and a different loop for the first digit, which cannot be `0`, and the last loop is to add all possible digits in the middle if `k%2 == 1` (k is odd).

Suggestions to optimize this are welcome!

Comment: 111 is also palindromic, or isn't it?

Comment: @jamylak that's because of the `x!=y` condition, not a biggie

Comment: @jamylak As OP said, I had explicitly omitted these numbers, I thought they were not palindromes, but I looked it up, and it seems they are.

Comment: Nice one, though it would be harder to adapt this approach to any number of digits.

Comment: This can be done an order of magnitude faster if you compute the numbers as `100*x+10*y+x` instead of through string interpolation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure underlying string parsing, a mechanism like this is involved

Comment: @prongs: yes, but the allocation of two strings and the parsing done by `%` is costly.

Comment: @larsmans True, thought of that too. And even if `int` does the same, there's the string conversion and format string parsing. It sure is faster.

Comment: @prongs I'm still thinking about `k` digits... It is hard, indeed.

Comment: @jadkik94: Yeah. I always say: "To generalize something you can either pay the `software engineering cost` or you can write a 500 line code" :P

Comment: @prongs Finally, here you have it with `k` digits!

Comment: @jadkik94: Wow! you are quite fast. I also did some coding: [http://pastie.org/3940027](http://pastie.org/3940027)

Answer (score 2):

For the generalisation to `k` digits, the most obvious way is to do something like:

```
palindromes = [x for x in itertools.permutations(string.digits, k) if x == x[::-1]]
```

But it isn't very efficient - it generates every possible 3-digit number, and discards the ones that aren't palindromes. However, it is possible to generalise solutions like @jadkik94's - what you need to do is generate every combination of *half* the length (rounding down), and stick the mirror of it on the end:

```
palindromes = [x + x[::-1] for x in permutations(digits, k//2)]
```

Will work for all even `k` - for odd `k`, you add an extra loop to put all of 0-9 in between the mirrored halves.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be converting the numbers to strings and checking if they are palindromes. To find the palindromes of the "k" number of digits, the list comprehension could be;

```
palindromes = [num for num in range(pow(10,k-1),pow(10,k)) if str(num) == str(num)[::-1]]
```